# Tracking results from a month ago and getting the results for each day - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am retrieving results from a `MySQL database` based on a `30 days ago`.  Here is what I am doing:

`"SELECT * FROM archived_check_in WHERE client_id = :id AND DATE(check_in_date) > DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))"`

Now I was wondering how I could actually get all my results from `30 days ago`, but actually also get the results for each day within that `30 day period`.

What is the best way to go about this?

Update:

Okay here is the example I am wanting to return:

```
    $j = 0;
    $response = '';

    $sql="SELECT * FROM archived_check_in WHERE client_id = :id AND DATE(check_in_date) > DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) ";
    $sth=$DBH->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(':id' =>$current_user->ID));
    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $i = 0;//<!-- used for that days total
        $response["row"][$j]["y"] = $row['check_in_date'];
        $response["row"][$j]["amount"] = $i + 1;
        $i++; 
    }
    $j++;
```

The `$response["row"][$j]...` would represent `each day` for the`30 day` lookup.

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? The question, worded as it is right no, is quite unclear, to me, at least.

Comment: If you want just the totals, you could `sum(columnToTotal)` and `group by check_in_date` in your query. If you want both, all the individual rows and the totals, then it is easier to just use php and loop over the data keeping a tally as you go.

Comment: @jonathanKuhn I am wanting to return data, via `json` to script containing an array of results for each specific day from a 30 day period.

Comment: If you're doing a lot of querying on this you probably want to have an indexed `DATE` column with just the date in it. Then you can use `GROUP BY` to get counts.

Comment: @tadman do you have any examples I could look at?

Comment: If all you want is the date and total then a query like this might work: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date, '%d-%b-%Y') AS dt,SUM(amount) as amt FROM archived_check_in WHERE ...(your where clause)... GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(check_in_date, '%d-%b-%Y')`

Comment: Do you want your array to have 30 elements? One for each day? You are going to aggregate results for each day in any way?

Comment: @geoandri, example `array(day 1 => array(all days data), day 2....)`

Comment: @jonathanKuhn, whats the purpose of `%d-%b-%Y`

Comment: That is the format for the date. It will make the date look like `03-JAN-2012`. I just prefer that format over the `2013-01-03` because it is obvious that the format is day-month-year. [You can see the possible formats here.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: Okay just for that, thank you so much.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn `YYYY-MM-DD` is the [ISO-8601 standard date format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). I've never seen `YYYY-DD-MM`, so that usually avoids the ambiguity. As a note, it's usually a bad idea to do date formatting at the database level. That's a **presentation** issue to be handled in the application, and only if necessary.

Comment: @tadman I am aware, I just usually work in Oracle as the database which defaults to 'DD-MON-YYYY' which is the format I listed above so I'm just used to working with it. The ambiguity comes more from the d-m-Y or m-d-Y standard which is locale dependent. I find it easier to use text for the month and not have an issue in any case (until you talk about language which doesn't affect me in my position with global customers that all speak english).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how you might get daily counts:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS day_count, DATE(check_in_date) AS day
  FROM archived_check_in
  WHERE client_id = :id
    AND DATE(check_in_date) > DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY))
  GROUP BY DATE(check_in_date)
```

Note that using `SELECT *` when you want just a few things is *extremely* wasteful. Whenever possible, select *only* the columns that you're interested in.

Since this needs to run the `DATE()` function on each row individually it will be painfully slow on larger data sets. That's where having a new `DATE` column specifically for this operation that has an associated `INDEX` is useful.

Comment: so this will retrieve results for each day correct?  And I can use `day_count` to store the current day it is on?

Comment: If you run it you should get day/count pairs. You can use those as you see necessary.

Comment: So you were talking about it being painfully slow?  Is there a way to make it quicker and be more efficient?

Comment: It depends on how many rows you have. Under 10K and it'll probably be fine unless you query aggressively, several times per minute for example. For larger volumes of data or more queries, create an indexed `DATE` column.

Comment: `1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY DATE(check_in_date)`

Comment: It was missing a closing bracket. Fixed.

Comment: I just found that to!

Comment: Okay I have a question, when using this I don't seem to get the server results of that row it has selected?  Is there a reason why?

Comment: If you want indexes to be used: `... check_in_date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 29 DAY`